# Mobile account, syncing certain files

Tags: network, data-synchronization

Under mobile account preferences I have selected "Home folder". What exactly is the home folder and how can I find out where mine is? What else does it include, for example does it include the folder Movies and Images? In mobile accounts is there a way to exclude certain files?

I forgot to ask but does enabling "sync home folder" mean that only the current user the account synced or all users of the computer have there home direcotry synced?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Your home folder is by default the folder that opens when you click Finder.

It's located at /Users/yourusername and is usually shortened to ~. This folder includes all the folders which contains your data such as Documents, Movies, Pictures, etc.

Mobile account syncing will sync everything in this folder. To skip items, go to Profile Manager → Mobility → Rules → Skip items.

Comment: So how can exclude a particular directory? For example /Users/yourusername/myvms

Comment: @Celeritas Edited :)

Comment: How do I get to Profile Manager?

Comment: @Celeritas FQDN/profilemanager or click the link in the service

Comment: You do know I'm not doing this from the command line?

Comment: @Celeritas I think I might be misunderstanding you generally — you're talking about OS X Server mobile accounts, right? Can you screenshot the settings where you set up the mobile account?

Comment: ok updated with screenshot

Comment: @Celeritas Ah, I thought you were the one configuring it from the server's Profile Manager. I don't think it's possible to exclude folders from an end-user point of view. Also, in answer to your last question, it syncs just your own user account and no-one else's.

Comment: Make sure you always have good and current backups. Home Sync has a very long history of trashing files and creating sync conflicts. Especially when used with multiple machines.